# Configurable product tax issues on asscoaiated products

Tags: catalog, tax, configurable-product, ce-1.6.2.0

We have some configurable products that we need to apply tax to but only on the chosen associated product.  For example we have a price of £89.95 on the configurable product itself but the associated products have different prices (say £89.9 and £29.95).  If the £29.95 associated product is chosen then tax should only be calculated on the £29.95 but for some reason it is being calculated on the headline configurable product price of £89.95 which obviously gives an incorrect tax amount being charged.

Has anyone else come across this and if so is there anyway of getting Magento to apply tax to only the associated product price?

Comment: Magento calculates taxes on configurable products and their price. The price for the simple product is ignored. I understand you correctly, that you want to charge your customer 89$ but calculate the tax against 39$.  - Where do I find the pound symbol?

Comment: Thanks Fabian, No I wanted to charge the simple product price and relevant tax and basically ignore the configurable product pricing and tax.  All sorted now though thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you just use something like [Simple Configurable Products](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-configurable-products.html)?

> This extension changes the way that the pricing of Configurable Products works in Magento.
>
> With Simple Configurable Products, the price for configurable products is taken directly from the associated simple products rather than the configurable product itself.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I've now done and it all seems to work great.  We did have a different extension running that did some of what we needed but completely ignored tax.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend BCP over SCP:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/better-configurable-products.html

You can find it here too:
http://www.nr-apps.com/store/bcp-better-configurable-products.html